# How to decrease the "bounce" rate when a rigidbody hits another?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I have a racket and a ball, both have rigidbodies. Ball has a physics material in it, which has bounce set to 0.8.

When I hit the ball with the racket, the ball goes too high up. Setting bounce to 0.0 and "Bounce Combine" to "minimum" helps it pretty much, but then it doesn't bounce at all. How can I adjust it?

Comment: What about setting bounce to a value between 0.0 and 0.8?

Comment: What I want is that when I hit it, it shouldn't go too high, but when the racket is static and ball hits it it should bounce like it's 0.8. So decreasing the bounce doesn't seem like an option...

Comment: Then instead of adapting the bounce of the ball, you should adapt the bounce of the different hit targets. E.g. wall = 0.8, racket = 0.4.

Comment: There is no wall. I guess there is no solution to what I  am asking. Thank you.